# Can someone help me quit iPhoto on my Mac?

Tags: mac, photos.app, applications

So I opened iPhoto to upload some photos. Then mid-download it stopped working. Now I can't shut down my computer or quit the iPhoto app!!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your request.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click or hold Control and click iPhoto in the dock, then hold down the alt/Option key and "Quit" will change to "Force Quit". Click that and it should kill it off.

Answer (score 4):

**Force Quit** unresponsive applications.

- Click the  Logo at the top left of your **Menu Bar** and select **Force Quit...**
- This will bring up the **Force Quit Applications** dialog where you can see unresponsive and/or all running applications.
- Choose the unresponsive application (in your case iPhoto) by clicking on it.
- Click the **Force Quit** Button

This dialog can be quickly invoked by using the keyboard shortcut:

- <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>esc ⎋</kbd> all together.

[image: Force Quit Applications Dialog]

Also, as the other answer states a right click or long press on the application's icon will bring up the dialog where you can quit the unresponsive application as well.